# sftp put - equivalent to rsync

Tags: remote, sftp, file-transfer

I would like to use the command `put` to recover an ongoing file transfer via `sftp` after a broken pipe.

Files should be uploaded only if the destination size is smaller than the one of the source file.

I don't have `ssh` access so `rsync` is not an option.

From the [sftp manual](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sftp&sektion=1), I tried specifying the flags `put -a -r source_dir/`. However, I got error messages in the transfer.

- Error: `Couldn't stat remote file: No such file or directory` for files not on server
- Error: `Destination file bigger or same size as source file` for  files that are already on server, and correctly shouldn't be transferred

Real example for the 1st error:

```
Uploading of file /Volumes/Seagate/amphioxus/raw_h5/9N0Bp0b0_m150427_041848_42182_c100810932550000001823181110291543_s1_p0.2.bax.h5.gz to /deposits/Pacbio_amphioxus/raw_h5/9N0Bp0b0_m150427_041848_42182_c100810932550000001823181110291543_s1_p0.2.bax.h5.gz failed!
Couldn't stat remote file: No such file or directory
```

Of course, the file exists in the source directory.

Any solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution to this, but a workaround is to mount the server locally and then simply copy the data.

[sshfs](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sshfs-to-mount-remote-file-systems-over-ssh) can be used to mount the remote directory:

```
sudo sshfs -o allow_other,default_permissions user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/ /mnt/local_directory
```

Then use

```
cp -ru
```

where u updates the files that are in the mounted remote directory with the missing ones.

Comment: sshfs needs an ssh access, which @aechchiki does not have.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to ask an administrator of the remote system to give you `ssh` access and use `rsync`, or maybe only `rsync` access if that is possible.

`sftp` can put (and get) files, but not directories (directory trees with their content).

A workaround is to **create a tarball [compressed] tarfile and put it with `sftp`**.

---

```
tar -cvzf filename.tar.gz source_dir/
```

If you need to restore from it, get it with `sftp` check the content

```
tar -tvf filename.tar.gz
```

make sure you are in the correct directory, and extract from the tarball,

```
tar -xvf filename.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

Use option `-a` of sftp. `man sftp` states that this instruct sftp to "Attempt to continue interrupted transfers rather than overwriting existing partial or complete copies of files.  If the partial contents differ from those being transferred, then the resultant file  is  likely to be corrupt.